# How can I make an Excel Sheet forget that it was generated from TFS?

Tags: excel, tfs

I have an Excel sheet which is generated by opening the result from some query based on TFS work items.

I'm using this Excel for my personal planning, but whenever I close the Sheet, it asks me if I want to publish my changes to TFS.

I want it to completely forget that it is derived from TFS, because I fear that some day I may publish my changes unintentionally.

I have tried saving the Excel Document in the oldest possible Excel format, but that doesn't help.

[image: Excel Dialog]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can copy the list and paste it into another Excel workbook.

Answer (score 25):

This is much easier than the other solutions on offer:

1. Click on a cell in the table
2. Open the Table Design tab on the ribbon
3. Click "Convert table to range"
4. Save the workbook

Done!

**Disclaimer:** I've only tried it with TFS 2012 & Office 2010.

Comment: I like this answer best. This works in Office 2013 and VisualStudio.com too.

Comment: This by far the best answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

There is a procedure that describes how to do this [at this Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/07/19/remove-tfs-project-excel.aspx), provided by Dennis Habib:

> "Close Excel. Disable the TFS addin by going to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\TfcOfficeShim.Connect and change the ‘LoadBehavior’ from ‘3’ to ‘0’. Open the .xls file. Wipe out the contents of the custom document properties (File -> Properties -> Custom). Save the file and exit Excel. Re-enable the TFS addin."

Comment: +1 that seems to be the correct answer to my problem. But I think the solution would be to propose a change request at Microsoft connect. Fidlding in the regestry to be able to add some private unshared notes?